# convex set definition intuition

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm in Baby Rudin chapter 2, and on page 32 he defines a set $$S$$ as convex if $$\forall x,y \in S \forall \gamma \in [0,1] : \gamma x + (1 - \gamma) y \in S$$ Looking up convex sets online, it seems that it means that the line between any $$x,y \in S$$ is also in $$S$$. Can someone give a good intuition for what the definition has to do with lines between points?

Comment: Do you have a good grasp on the idea of a convex set? Can you "visualize" or "feel" them? What are some of their characteristic properties?

Comment: Draw some non-convex sets.

Comment: Every point on that line can be written in the form $\gamma x+(1-\gamma)y$. Maybe it's more obvious if written as $y+\gamma(x-y)$.

Comment: Vercassivelaunos was thinking about it and came up with this, this makes sense thanks!